# ERROR al traer una imagen con PHP para un HERO de una web

Tags: php, sql, html5, web, backend

estoy obteniendo el siguiente error al traer una URL con PHP en local para mostrar una imagen de un "hero". Parece que estoy utilizando algo obsoleto. He estado googleando pero no entiendo realmente donde esta el problema. Alguien me puede ayudar?

[Deprecation] Resource requests whose URLs contained both removed whitespace (`\n`, `\r`, `\t`) characters and less-than characters (`<`) are blocked. Please remove newlines and encode less-than characters from places like element attribute values in order to load these resources. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5735596811091968 for more details.

Este sería el código que estoy utilizando para el hero (en un template aparte):

```
<div class="container pt-4">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-12 hero">
          <img src="img/<?php echo ($imagen) ? $imagen : $titulo . '.jpg';  ?>" class="img-fluid">
          <h2 class="text-uppercase d-none d-md-block"><?php echo $titulo; ?></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y esto el inicio del código de la pagina (Nosotros) donde me da el error.

```
 <?php
    $titulo = 'nosotros';
    include 'templates/header.php';
    include 'templates/hero.php';
?>


<div class="container pt-4">
    <div class="row">
        <main class="col-lg-8 contenido-principal">
          <h2 class="d-block d-md-none text-uppercase text-center"><?php echo $titulo; ?></h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed convallis ac risus sit amet condimentum. Duis pellentesque vitae erat a varius. Donec tincidunt, risus sit amet varius tincidunt, turpis arcu ullamcorper ligula, at feugiat turpis massa vitae erat. Nam sit amet posuere urna. Mauris consequat elit in tellus fringilla, in mollis dolor feugiat. Vivamus fringilla eros sed leo maximus rhoncus. Phasellus sit amet vehicula diam. Pellentesque ut lorem ex. Donec sed accumsan velit.</p>
```

Comentar que el nombre de la imagen que quiero mostrar en .jpg se llama igual que el titulo de la pagina para ahorrar en código.

Comment: Es necesario ver que resulta de la ejecución del código. No me refiero a la página interpretada por el browser si no la respuesta de tu servidor. Si usas google chrome puedes ver el resultado en la pestaña network. Con eso es posible ayudar.

Comment: Según la pestaña sources del google chrome este es el codigo que me da error pq no se define correctamente la url de la imagen: <div class="container pt-4">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-12 hero">
            <img src="img/<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: imagen in <b>/Users/fulanito/Desktop/development/carolina_spa/templates/hero.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
servicios.jpg" class="img-fluid">
            <h2 class="text-uppercase d-none d-md-block">servicios</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas revisar si existe la variable `$imagen` primero que nada, ésta línea en concreto:

```
<?php echo ($imagen) ? $imagen : $titulo . '.jpg';
```

El problema, concretamente es que mientras que `($imagen) ?` revisa si la variable es true o false no tiene forma de saber **antes** si existe o no. Esta técnica funciona siempre y cuando tus errores sean suprimidos, pero debido al nivel de errores que reporta PHP, el resultado es un **Notice**.

La solución es usar la función `isset()` para saber si la variable existe antes de revisar cualquier otra condición con ella:

```
<?php echo isset($imagen) ? $imagen : $titulo . '.jpg';
```

La otra opción (que no es recomendable durante desarrollo) es suprimir los errores:

```
<?php
// Desactivar toda notificación de error
error_reporting(0);

// Notificar solamente errores de ejecución
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// Notificar todos los errores excepto E_NOTICE
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

Comment: Ok, voy a probar a ver si con isset lo conseguimos....